# PDO search fails with multiple numbers

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to search a database using either a name OR a reference number (in the format ABC/X/012345/XX).

The name searches appear perfectly, as do reference number searches if I look for ABC or XX.

But if I search for the full reference number, no matches are found. The problem also happens with a partial reference number search containing more than one number (e.g. ABC/X/01 or even just 01).

I don't get an error message and the 'Sorry, your search returned no results' message isn't displayed, which would seem to suggest it's finding the correct entries, just not displaying them.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

$search_term = "%".$search."%";

try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT user_id, name FROM users WHERE name LIKE :search_term OR ref_number LIKE :search_term');
    $STH->bindParam(':search_term', $search_term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH->execute();
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($STH->fetchColumn() > 0) {
        while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
        echo "<a href='viewprofile.php?user_id=".$row['user_id']."'>".$row['name']."</a><br/>";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Sorry, your search returned no results.</p>';
    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PDOStatement::fetchColumn($index = 0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) fetches a whole row and returns the `$index`th column's value. If you want to test how many rows your query returns, use [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)